# Некорректно отрабатывает display-font: optional

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, шрифты

Есть заголовок в стиле Montserrat 900, подгружаемый с сервера. Но при первой загрузке сайта шрифт не успевает подгрузиться, отчего появляется установленный на компьютере шрифт (Georgia), и только после этого загружается основной шрифт. Это все создает неприятный скачок особенно на мобильной версии сайта, которого я пытаюсь избежать всеми силами.
Я хотел использовать font-display: optional, так как он решает мою проблему, подключал в следующем виде:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 900;
 src: local('Montserrat'), url('...') format('woff2');
}
```

Однако шрифт все равно продолжает переключаться с Georgia на Montserrat и дергать весь контент ниже.
Также я пробовал использовать FontAPI, для отслеживания загрузки шрифтов, ограничивать рендер заголовка, так как весь сайт использует React, при помощи React.memo, использовать тэг preload для загрузки шрифта до первого рендера - все безрезультатно.

Comment: Почитайте https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/470870/

Comment: @Quazimorda, да, я уже открывал данную статью, благодарю. Но, к сожалению, страница успевает отрисоваться до того, как успевает загрузиться шрифт даже с тегом preload.
Сейчас я нашел инструмент WebFontLoader, возможно, он поможет решить проблему с optional.